# Decrypt Fernet Encrypted Text(PYTHON) in SWIFT

Tags: python, swift, xcode, cryptography, cryptoswift

I have generated an Encrypted Text is Python using cryptography

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
message = "my deep dark secret".encode()

f = Fernet(key)
encrypted = f.encrypt(message)
# decrypting
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
encrypted = b"...encrypted bytes..."

f = Fernet(key)
decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)
```

ENCRYPTION INFO:

```
KEY: b'3b-Nqg6ry-jrAuDyVjSwEe8wrdyEPQfPuOQNH1q5olE='
ENC_MESSAGE: b'gAAAAABhBRBGKSwa7AluNJYhwWaHrQGwAA8UpMH8Wtw3tEoTD2E_-nbeoAvxbtBpFiC0ZjbVne_ZetFinKSyMjxwWaPRnXVSVqz5QqpUXp6h-34_TL7BaDs='
```

Now I'm trying to Decrypt it in Swift but to no luck.
So Far I've Tried CryptoSwift with the following:

```
func testdec(){
        let str = "3b-Nqg6ry-jrAuDyVjSwEe8wrdyEPQfPuOQNH1q5olE="
        let ba = "gAAAAABhBRBGKSwa7AluNJYhwWaHrQGwAA8UpMH8Wtw3tEoTD2E_-nbeoAvxbtBpFiC0ZjbVne_ZetFinKSyMjxwWaPRnXVSVqz5QqpUXp6h-34_TL7BaDs="
        let encodedString = Base64FS.decodeString(str: String(str.utf8))
        print(encodedString.count)
        
        let first4 = String(ba.prefix(25))
        let start = first4.index(first4.startIndex, offsetBy: 9)
        let end = first4.index(first4.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let iv = String(first4[start..<end])

        let starta = ba.index(ba.startIndex, offsetBy: 25)
        let enda = ba.index(ba.endIndex, offsetBy: -32)
        let cipher_text = String(ba[starta..<enda])
        let cipher_text_bt: [UInt8] = [UInt8](base64: cipher_text)
        print(cipher_text)
        
        print(iv)
        let cipher_text_bta: [UInt8] = [UInt8](base64: ba)
//        print(encodedString.bytes.count)
//        let key_bta: [UInt8] = [UInt8](base64: "RgSADaf8w4v9vokuncyzWRbP5hkdhXSETdxIHLDHtKg=")
//        let iv_bt: [UInt8] = [UInt8](base64: "7KUDrsPmb28KQqOWv00KXw==")
//        let cipher_text_bt: [UInt8] = [UInt8](base64: "gAAAAABhBQ837KUDrsPmb28KQqOWv00KX2KjsP2ar6lHLqIPUKSvF1WHiruquG-tiAEkrCZZbm-lFR9ZwxsqVcXovmQ3Hv6pWw==")
        
        do{
            print("A")
            let aes = try AES(key: encodedString, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv.bytes), padding: .pkcs7)
            print("B")
            let cipherTexta = try aes.decrypt(cipher_text_bt)
            print(cipherTexta)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
16
WaHrQGwAA8UpMH8Wtw3tEoTD2E_-nbeoAvxbtBpFiC0ZjbVne_ZetFinKSyMjxw
RBGKSwa7AluNJYhw
A
B
invalidData
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md)? I don't see any HMAC, to name just one issue.

Comment: Fernet uses 128 Bit with PKCS7 Padding in CBC Mode. It doesn't have HMAC. If you see the code, There is no HMAC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get your cipher text decrypted using only Apple provided sources. If you support iOS 13 and up, I suggest you use `CryptoKit` to verify the HMAC, but for now, I've adopted a full `CommonCrypto` solution.

First a minor extension to create `Data` from base64 URL strings.

```swift
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

extension Data {
    init?(base64URL base64: String) {
        var base64 = base64
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
        if base64.count % 4 != 0 {
            base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - base64.count % 4))
        }
        self.init(base64Encoded: base64)
    }
}
```

The decrypt function is a bit obscure, but it supports the very old `CommonCrypto` syntax. `withUnsafeBytes` syntax would be cleaner, but this is a quick workaround.

```swift
func decrypt(ciphertext: Data, key: Data, iv: Data) -> Data {
    var decryptor: CCCryptorRef?
    
    defer {
        CCCryptorRelease(decryptor)
    }
    
    var key = Array(key)
    var iv = Array(iv)
    var ciphertext = Array(ciphertext)
    
    CCCryptorCreate(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt), CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES), CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), &key, key.count, &iv, &decryptor)
    
    var outputBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: CCCryptorGetOutputLength(decryptor, ciphertext.count, false))
    CCCryptorUpdate(decryptor, &ciphertext, ciphertext.count, &outputBytes, outputBytes.count, nil)
    
    var movedBytes = 0
    var finalBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: CCCryptorGetOutputLength(decryptor, 0, true))
    CCCryptorFinal(decryptor, &finalBytes, finalBytes.count, &movedBytes)
    
    return Data(outputBytes + finalBytes[0 ..< movedBytes])
}
```

Then the HMAC. I suggest you use `CryptoKit` if you can. This function is of course fixed, there might be ways to make this dynamic. For Fernet however, only SHA256 is supported.

```swift
func verifyHMAC(_ mac: Data, authenticating data: Data, using key: Data) -> Bool {
    var data = Array(data)
    var key = Array(key)
    var macOut = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), &key, key.count, &data, data.count, &macOut)
    return Array(mac) == macOut
}
```

All of that together comes down to the following code. Note that I do not check the version and/or timestamp, which should be done according to the spec.

```swift
let fernetKey   = Data(base64URL: "3b-Nqg6ry-jrAuDyVjSwEe8wrdyEPQfPuOQNH1q5olE=")!
let signingKey  = fernetKey[0 ..< 16]
let cryptoKey   = fernetKey[16 ..< fernetKey.count]

let fernetToken = Data(base64URL: "gAAAAABhBRBGKSwa7AluNJYhwWaHrQGwAA8UpMH8Wtw3tEoTD2E_-nbeoAvxbtBpFiC0ZjbVne_ZetFinKSyMjxwWaPRnXVSVqz5QqpUXp6h-34_TL7BaDs=")!
let version     = Data([fernetToken[0]])
let timestamp   = fernetToken[1 ..< 9]
let iv          = fernetToken[9 ..< 25]
let ciphertext  = fernetToken[25 ..< fernetToken.count - 32]
let hmac        = fernetToken[fernetToken.count - 32 ..< fernetToken.count]

let plainText = decrypt(ciphertext: ciphertext, key: cryptoKey, iv: iv)
print(plainText, String(data: plainText, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Non utf8")
print(verifyHMAC(hmac, authenticating: version + timestamp + iv + ciphertext, using: signingKey))
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It actually worked. Thanks alot!

Comment: Bram, this is amazing. I also need the other way (encrypting in swift and decoding in python) as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72793619/exchanging-encrypted-messages-between-python-and-swift  . Any chance you could have a look ?

Comment: @Bram But how do I generate the key using a password and a salt? In the example, you already have the key, but how to create it with Swift? Assuming I have a password that a user has entered, and a salt. Could you please update the example?

Comment: I found an answer on how to generate the key here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62681784/11004423